# Abstract Algebra Subgroup Help

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, abelian-groups

Suppose that $G$ is an additive abelian group. Show that $H = \{a \in G\,|\, a + a = 2a = 0\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Proof:

(1) Nonempty
Now $e = a + a = 2a = 0 \in H$, so $H$ is nonempty.

(2) Closure 
Let $a, b \in H$. Then $a + b$, where $a + b \in H$. Thus, $H$ is closed.

(3) Inverse 
Let $a \in G$ and $-a \in G$. Suppose $a = -a$. Then $a + a = 0 \in H$. Hence, $H$ has an inverse.

Therefore, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I am not sure if my Inverse part of the proof is correct.

Comment: (1) You have to show H contains 0. (2) You have to show that a+b is in H. You can't just say it is. (3) You have to show that every element of H has an inverse that is also in H.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment above says, your proofs for non-emptiness and closure are not correct. Try instead these hints, with full proofs in the spoilers.

Non-empty: Use the fact that $0+0=0$.

> $H \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} \{ a \in G\ :\ 2a = 0\},$ and $0 + 0 = 0$, so $0 \in H$. Hence, $H$ is non-empty.

Closure: Use the fact that $G$ is abelian.

> Let $a,b \in H$. Then, $2a = 0$ and $2b = 0$. Since $G$ is abelian, $2(a+b) = (a+b) + (a+b) = 2a + 2b = 0 + 0 = 0$. Therefore, $a+b \in H$.

Inverse: Use the fact that for all $a \in H$, $a+a = 0 \implies a = -a$.

> Since $a+a=0$ for all $a \in H$, then $a= -a$. Then, $2(-a) = 2a = 0$. Hence, $-a \in H$. One should also take care to note that $-a$ exists in $G$, since $a \in G$ is an element of a group.